# i have problem with my code during run-time (logical)

Tags: c, compiler-errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKHPy.jpg)while running the 'binary to decimal' program it's just skip asking 'y or n' question what is my mistake ?
code does not have any compile-time error it seems to be something with my logic and i can not figure out what is the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void BinaryToDecimal() {   
   int q,z,x,r;
    q=z=0;
    printf("\nplease enter a binary digit:");
    scanf("%i",&x);
    while (x!=0) {
        r=x%10;
        z+=r*pow(2,q);
        q++;
        x/=10;
    }
    printf("%i",z);
}
int main () {
    char YesOrNo;
    BinaryToDecimal();
    printf("\nDo you need it again? answer with 'y' or 'n': "); 
    scanf("%c",&YesOrNo);
    while (YesOrNo =='y' || YesOrNo =='Y' ) {
    BinaryToDecimal();
    printf("\n'y' and 'n'?");
    scanf("%c",&YesOrNo);   
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

i asked AI it gave me a code but i could not recognize the differences i checked that line by line and still feeling blind

Comment: OT: don't use `pow` for powers of integers and even less for powers of 2.